# How can I use other library to my android production app

Tags: android, upload

I developed an app. I have use many third party library. Now I want to deploy my app in play store. But I have some doubts regarding licence issue. Can I deploy my app in play store without any third party library licence issue.

Comment: It depends on the license of each library. Some licenses allow you to use them unconditionally. Others require you to show credit to the creator of the license. Some will allow you to use their library in a development environment but when you want to release to the public you need to pay.

Comment: you have to give them credits , otherwise in future you may be some trouble related license issue. So better is that take an activity which shows all licenses